# How to make the Navbar dissapear when the page is directed to a page not found in React using react router dom?

Tags: reactjs

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from '../Pages/Home';
import { Login } from '../Pages/Login';
import { Register } from '../Pages/Register';

function App() {
  return (
        <Router>
              <Navbar/>
              <Routes>
                <Route path='/home' element={ <Home />}></Route>
                <Route path='/login' element={ <Login />}></Route>
                <Route path='/register' element={ <Register />}></Route>
                <Route path="*" element={ <h1>Page Not Found</h1>}></Route>
              </Routes>
        </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can't think a logic how to make it disappear when it is directed in page not found.

Comment: How about before you render your component you check the name of the path and depending on this you rending it or not?

Answer (score 2):

Wich version are you using? **I think** you can use the `useLocation()` function. Something like this:

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  const validRoutes = ['/home', '/login', '/register'];

  const isNavbarVisible = validRoutes.includes(location.pathname);

  return (
    <Router>
      {isNavbarVisible && <Navbar />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>Page Not Found</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have used this a long time ago. Maybe still work

Answer (score 0):

First, we should change the URL of the NotFoundPage when accessing invalid address to be "/404" as the following:

```
//In App.tsx  
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout/>}>
  ...
    <Route path="/404" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/404" />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

After that, we can easily detect if we are in NotFoundPage to remove the NavBar

```
const AppLayout = ({ links }: NavigationProps) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const isNotFoundPage = useMemo(() => pathname === "/404", [pathname]);
  ...
  {!isNotFoundPage && (
  <NavBar
    className="navigator-container"
    sx={{ position: "relative", paddingRight: "0px !important" }}
  >
  ...
  </NavBar>)}

  <main>
    <Outlet />
  </main>
}
```